# Can pip.conf specify two index-url at the same time?

Tags: pip

I have tried using pip with index-url in `pip.conf`. However, i  can not make sure that we can get all the necessary python library. So, i want to know if pip support specify more than one `index-url` in `[global]` section in `pip.conf`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you want more than one package index you have to use the `--extra-index-url`

From the [pip man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=pip):

```
   -i,--index-url <url>
          Base URL of Python Package Index (default https://pypi.python.org/simple/).

   --extra-index-url <url>
          Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition to --index-url.
```

In `pip.conf` the name of settings must be put without `--`. From the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration):

> The names of the settings are derived from the long command line option, e.g. if you want to use a different package index (--index-url) and set the HTTP timeout (--default-timeout) to 60 seconds your config file would look like this:

```
[global]
timeout = 60
index-url = http://download.zope.org/ppix
```

So you can add in your `pip.conf`

```
extra-index-url = http://myserver.com/pip
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify multiple indices in `extra-index-url` within `pip.conf`?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39085648/691859

Answer (score 122):

In your `pip.conf`, you will also have to add both of the index hosts as trusted, so would look something like this:

```
[global]
index-url = http://download.zope.org/simple
trusted-host = download.zope.org
               pypi.org
               secondary.extra.host
extra-index-url= https://pypi.org/simple
                 http://secondary.extra.host/simple
```

In this example, you have a primary index and two extra index urls and all hosts are trusted.

If you don't specify the host as trusted, you will get the following error:

> The repository located at secondary.extra.host is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host secondary.extra.host'.

Cheers!

Comment: the url to pypi changed to pypi.org

Comment: To save you a bit of struggle: the url for pypi is now `https://pypi.org/simple`

Answer (score 25):

updating [radtek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2023392/radtek) 's answer with the new URL to pypi.

It changed to https://pypi.org

So for your pip to be able to fall back to the original pypi server you'll need to add "https://pypi.org/simple" as an extra-index-url while keeping your local server as index-url. 
Don't forget to add both to your "trusted-host" list

This update is based on the comment of [onelaview](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543783/onelaview): "Official PyPI now supports HTTPS so you can specify https://pypi.org/simple/ for extra-index-URL and avoid specifying pypi.org in trusted-host."

---

So your pip.conf needs to be containing the following:

```
[global]
index-url = https://somedomain.org/simple
trusted-host = somedomain.org
               pypi.org
               secondary.extra.host
extra-index-url= http://pypi.org/simple <= either one of these is fine
                 https://pypi.org/simple <= either one of these is fine
                 http://secondary.extra.host/simple
```

Comment: Official PyPI now supports HTTPS so you can specify `https://pypi.org/simple/` for extra-index-url and avoid specifying `pypi.org` in trusted-host.

Comment: @onelaview Can you tell me why pypi.org should not be included as a trusted source, please?

Comment: @NaveenDennis If you refer *pypi.org* using `https` I believe a merit of HTTPS protocol already verifies a trust for you which means Pip doesn't require you to explicitly say you trust this host. HTTPS works on SSL/TLS protocol that your computer will verify the trust with a certificate authority chain, the same thing when you navigate some `https` website from your web browser and your web browser doesn't need to ask you whether you trust this site before letting you access it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this by setting an environment variable:

```
export PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=http://localhost:8080/simple/
```

which is equivalent to

```
[global]
extra-index-url = http://localhost:8080/simple/
```

but does not require a `pip.conf` file

Answer (score 5):

I'd add to @Tomasz Bartkowiak answer. You can pass multiple URLs to a `PIP_TRUSTED_HOST`,`PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` using spaces:

```
export PIP_TRUSTED_HOST="somedomain.org pypi.org secondary.extra.host"

export PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="http://pypi.org/simple https://pypi.org/simple http://secondary.extra.host/simple"
```