# How do i declare more than one extra-index-url in pip.conf

Tags: python, pip

Where  would I set this in pip.conf?

I want to add two(2) extra-index-urls in pip.conf, but I did not find a solution how to do this after some research in the docs.

Answer (score 33):

Although the example in [the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) is for `--find-links`, it says:

> Appending options like `--find-links` can be written on multiple lines:

```
[global]
find-links =
    http://download.example.com

[install]
find-links =
    http://mirror1.example.com
    http://mirror2.example.com
```

So I believe you may be able to do the same for `extra-index-url`. While I am having issues with the indices I'm using to test, I can confirm that passing the argument twice at the command line has the same effect as separating the two indices on multiple lines like this example does.

edit: I can confirm that this does indeed work for `extra-index-url`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `index-url` plus `extra-index-urls`, for example:

```
#content of ~/.config/pip/pip.conf
[global]
index-url=https://<some-other-index>
extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
```