# pip install from private repository but `install_requires` from PyPI

Tags: python, pip, artifactory

I'm using Artifactory to host a private package to install using `pip`. I have `~/.pypirc` looking like

```
[distutils]
index-servers = local
[local]
repository: https://path.to/api/pypi/mypackage
username: me
password: mypassword
```

and `~/.pip/pip.conf` looking like

```
[global]
index-url = https://me:mypassword@path.to/api/pypi/mypackage/simple
```

So then I'm able to upload the wheel without a problem using my `setup.py` by doing `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local`, and then can `pip install mypackage`. This will find the package and install it; however, it is not able to install the required packages for my package that I've defined in `install_requires` in `setup.py` because it is looking for them as local packages. For example, it says

```
Looking in indexes: https://me:mypassword@path.to/api/pypi/mypackage/simple
Collecting mypackage
  Downloading https://path.to/api/pypi/mypackage/packages/mypackage/0.0.1/mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting boto3==1.9.74 (from mypackage)
```

My `setup.py` looks like

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="mypackage",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="me",
    author_email="me@somewhere.com",
    description="Private stuff",
    url="",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=['boto3==1.9.74']
)
```

Is there a way to specify that the `install_requires` should not be from `mypackage` but from PyPI and should be `pip` installed normally?

Comment: Please look at [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889494/can-pip-conf-specify-two-index-url-at-the-same-time) answers, for multiple urls in pip config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can pip.conf specify two index-url at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889494/can-pip-conf-specify-two-index-url-at-the-same-time)