# python setuptools - can you download from specific repository?

Tags: python, setuptools

`install_requires` seems to automatically install the packages using `pip`. That's great, but I want to install some packages from `conda`, `conda-forge`, `github`, `bitbucket`, or elsewhere.

Is there a way to do this directly in the install requires? Something like this:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'python-dotenv',
        'conda pymssql',
        'conda -c conda-forge ibm_db',
        'ssh://git@bitbucket.repos.com:23606/repos/package.git',
        'https://github.com/someone/something.git',
        ...
    ],
```

That would be awesome but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: I can't imagine you can force it to use conda, but this syntax might work for git: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998253/1011724

Comment: Otherwise, a pip config file might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34290398/1011724 but I guess that will only be useful if you have control over the environment. If you use case is for a publicly distributed package then I guess that won't help you.