# Dockerfile and pip.conf and jfrog- Unable to download packages when installing requirements file

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile which has a bunch of commands and then reaches to a position where it does a
pip install -r requirements.txt

Before this point in the file, it copies the pip.conf to its workspace.
The problem am facing is that the requirements file has general pypi packages like boto3, werkzeug etc. as well as few packages from our Jfrog artifactory.

Now I understand that we need to configure the pip.conf file and provide the index-url = , which I have provided.

What is happening is:

1. If I keep the pip.conf blank, the general packages like boto and stuff gets downloaded and installed automatically when the requirements are being installed, but for obvious reasons the packages from the Jfrog artifactory are not recognized.
2. If I put in the pip.conf index and index-url, trusted-hosts configurations - the basic packages like boto and all are not getting installed.

This could be a docker issue or a pip issue or both, I am really stepping in on new soil here so am not well versed with these things. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+indexes

Comment: `--extra-index-url`. Can be used multiple times. In the `pip.conf` it's a list of URLs separated by spaces/newlines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926975/7976758